# warning: method definition for ‘+init’ not found - but it is implemented

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and trying to build a simple class. I have now a working piece of code, but for some reason I cannot get rid of two warnings. What am I doing wrong?
* I'm compiling with GCC from the terminal if it makes any difference.

Code:

```
#import <objc/Object.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface ValueAssignment : Object
{
    char name;
}

+ (void) setVar:(char) x_name;
+ (id) init;
@end

@implementation ValueAssignment

- (void) setVar:(char) x_name{
    name = x_name;
}

- (id) init {
    if(self = [super init]){
        name = ' ';
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
@end

/** Main program for the program execution entry **/
int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
//    id o = [ValueAssignment new];
    id o = [[ValueAssignment alloc] init];

    [o setVar:'9'];

    printf("Bye.\n");
}
```

Compiling with:

```
gcc -arch i386 -o hello -l objc test.m
```

Output:

```
test.m:26: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘ValueAssignment’
test.m:26: warning: method definition for ‘+init’ not found
test.m:26: warning: method definition for ‘+setVar:’ not found
```

---

Edit:

If I change the implementation part to `+ (id) init {` then I get the following output:

```
test.m: In function ‘+[ValueAssignment setVar:]’:
test.m:16: warning: instance variable ‘name’ accessed in class method
test.m: In function ‘+[ValueAssignment init]’:
test.m:21: warning: instance variable ‘name’ accessed in class method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the interface. You declared `init` as a class method instead of an instance method:

```
+ (id) init;
```

should be:

```
- (id) init;
```

Same for the `setVar:` method.

And unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, change:

```
id o = [[ValueAssignment alloc] init];
```

to:

```
ValueAssignment *o = [[ValueAssignment alloc] init];
```

Comment: I did. You changed the wrong thing. Read my answer.

Comment: OK, now it gives me a segmentation fault.. :-\  -- Anyway, could you please say in a sentence what - and + mean? I thought its 'private' and 'public'. --Thanks!

Comment: No, it's class and instance. Please find a good Objective-C tutorial to learn the basics of the language. As for the segmentation fault, that is a whole new issue. This question has been answered and solved. Close this one out. It would be best to post a new question about the segmentation fault after you have made some effort to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a class method +init and an instance method -init.